# Jquery append to selector adding variable possible?

Tags: jquery

I have code:

```
<p>aaa</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>ccc</p>
```

I would like to preprend a checkbox to every paragraph with:

```
$("p").prepend("<input type='checkbox' name='xxx' id='xxx' /><label for='test'>xxx</label></span>");
```

but instead of xxx I would need to enter some variable, like counter: var1, var2, var3... How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prepend` as function:

```
$("p").prepend(function(index, htmlContent) {
    console.log(htmlContent); //aaa, bbb, ccc -> the content of selected element
    return "<input type='checkbox' name='xxx' id='"+index+"' /><label for='test'>xxx</label></span>";
});
```

Comment: The first version didn't work, this version with return works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You search probably for so called "Template literals (Template strings)"

See please following snippet for an example of the usage.

For more information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
// $("p").prepend("<input type='checkbox' name='xxx' id='xxx' /><label for='test'>xxx</label></span>");

//let tmp = "<input type='checkbox' name='xxx' id='xxx' /><label for='test'>xxx</label></span>";



$("p").each(function( index ) {

   let name = `name_${index}`;
   let id =  `id_${index}`;
   let text = `${$(this).text()} ${index}`

   let output = `<input type='checkbox' name='${name}' id='${id}' /><label for='${name}'>${text}</label></span>`;
  
  console.log(output);
  $(this).html(output);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>aaa</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>ccc</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a string variable at first place in which you define the xxx variable value correctly, then use that string variable into the prepend! It should work fine

[edit]

`const newXXX = "<input type='checkbox' name=" + 'xxx new value' + " id='xxx' /><label for='test'>xxx</label></span>"`

`$("p").prepend(newXXX)`

You can use the any string concat method

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if I understand, could you make me a simple example please?